# logic question: How to say $A \cap (B \cup C)$ in english

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

$A$, the set of people who like to make bbq, 
$B$, the set of people whose house is blue, 
$C$, the set of people hosting a cat.
I've been asked to say $A \cap (B \cup C)$ in english but i'm not sure how. 
I tried "People who like to bbq and people who live in a blue house or have a cat." but Im pretty sure my phrase translates to $(A \cap B) \cup C$ since $\cap$ is prioretary.

Comment: People who like to barbecue and also either live in a blue house or have a cat (or both).

Comment: Small technical point when translating set theory to English: the set of *people who like bbq and people who own a cat* is a union. On the other hand, the set of *people who like bbq and own a cat* is an intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to translate the set notation into English.

- Intersection: $\cap=$ "And"
- Union: $\cup=$ "Or"

So the expression becomes:

- $A \cap (B \cup C) \rightarrow A \ and \ (B \ or \ C)$
- "People who like to make BBQ and either live in a blue house or host a cat, or both."

Answer (score 1):

Another way to say ...${A \cap (B \cup C)= (A \cap B)\cup (A \cap C)}$ , i.e., A set of people who either live in blue house and like to make bbq  , or they have cat and also like to make bbq

Comment: I actually like your transformation of the set notation the best because it leaves the least amount of ambiguity when stated as English clauses.